# SNTP requestTime on SDK 14 and above

Tags: java, android

I am developing a software using network time:

```
 if (client.requestTime("0.pool.ntp.org" , 850)) {
   long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() –
              client.getNtpTimeReference();
   …………………
   ……………….
}
```

This works OK for SDKs below 14, but it doesn’t even pass the if statement when trying on SDKs 14 and above.
Need help plese.